# Restrict published SharePoint-hosted app to a single Site Collection

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin, app

Our SharePoint-hosted app has been published to the App Catalog successfully. Is it possible to restrict it to a single Site Collection so that nobody is able to add it to another site collections?

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1** - If you are on premise.

**Consider moving you site collection to a different web application and designate a separate app catalogue for the web application**. This way you will be able to isolate the apps from other web applications/site collections.

**Approach 2** - If you are on Office 365 or the first approach is not suitable.

Convert the add in to provider hosted add in and implement an add-in event receiver.

**Implement an AppInstalling event and check before hand where the user is trying to install the add in.** If it is one off the target site collection/site then allow the installation or throw a permission denied error.

To read about the add in events please refer this [Create an add-in event receiver in SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220052.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try creating a app under specific site collection.Please refer blog https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/site-collection-app-catalog